# Kendo UI: How to SUM two fields and show in a 3rd one

Tags: javascript, php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i'm currently using kendo ui, and i got a little problem, got the grid

```
schema: 
                                 {
                                     data: "data",
                                     total: function(response) 
                                     {
                                         return response.data.length;
                                     },
                                     model: 
                                     {
                                             id: "id",
                                             fields: 
                                             {
                                                 clasificacion      :{editable: false},
                                                 tipo_rubros        :{editable: false },
                                                 rubro              :{editable: false },
                                                 proveedor_rubro    :{editable:false },
                                                 valor              :{editable: false ,type:"number"},
                                                 num_factura        :{editable: true },
                                                 neto               :{editable: true ,type:"number"},
                                                 iva                :{editable: true ,type:"number"},
                                                 observacion        :{editable: true },
                                                 fecha_factura      :{editable: true  },
                                             }
                                     }                      
                                 },
                                  group: {

                                        field: "tipo_rubros", aggregates: [
                                       { field: "valor", aggregate: "sum"}
                                        ]
                                  },
                                 aggregate: [ { field: "valor", aggregate: "sum" },
                                 ]
                         },
```

I want to do the math operation between "neto" and "iva" and in real time the answer appear on the "valor" field.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement save function for your grid. It is fired when you have changed cell value and pressed enter.
Your question does not include the whole source code, but the implementation should be something like this:

```
save: function (e) {
   yourDataSource.valor = e.model.neto + e.model.iva;
   yourGrid.data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
   yourGrid.data('kendoGrid').refresh();
}
```

Hopefully this helps.